# Circuit and layout review -- micro controller multiple outputs and different voltage domains

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, circuit-design, opto-isolator

I would be happy to get feedback on a small circuit that I am designing. (Disclaimer: my experience in circuit design is limited and I not the most proficient person in using the design tools, so please be gentle).

The aim is to have a microcontroller (here: Wemos D1 mini) read one sensor (likely DS18B20) and control two outputs, one on/off, one in PWM.

The controller and the sensor should be running on 5V while the two loads (a fan [on/off operation], LED strip [PWM controlled]) will need 12V.

The circuit I came up with is the following

[image: Wemos controller, 1 input, 2 outputs]

Note that I added the `J[1-6]` pads as that was the only way at least I figured out to easily have external connection terminals for the voltages when laying out the board (see below).

The idea of the circuit is that I have the 5V circuit and the 12V circuit and they are linked via opto couplers so that there is no mixing of the voltage domains. The opto couplers in turn drive some beefy MOSFETs to make sure they can take the load (note that the models displayed are similar but not necessarily identical).

I built this circuit on a bread board and it seems to work as expected. Nonetheless I wonder if there are things that could be improved, e.g. protections that one might want to add or other things. (I might have gotten the polarity of the MOSFETs wrong in the drawing, for my model the circuit seems to work with this layout)

I went and tried to lay out the whole design for a perf board and for this step the result is this.

[image: Wemos circuit 1 input 2 outputs perf board design]

Once more in case somebody has obvious comments on how to improve things before I start soldering, that would be very kind :)

In case there is anything unclear about the circuit do not hesitate to ask for clarification.

EDIT: picture has been updated with thicker "traces" for high current paths.

Comment: Your power tracks are way too thin. The optos do not stop the ‘mixing’ of your power domains - they are joined by 0V. Be sure to understand where the current is flowing and size your wiring appropriately.

Comment: Thank you @Kartman for the input. I did not try to draw the wiring according to the load on them. Your comment is well taken of course, mostly the LED strip will draw quite a bit of power, so I would dimension all the wires that carry that current large(r). 

You are right that the circuits are coupled via ground; I was trying see if I can avoid this, but felt that I'd eventually be going to something that is effectively the same ground as the 12V as I was/am planning to get the 5V from a step-down DCDC converter from the same 12V source

Answer (score 1):

Your missing a current limiting resistor for the led on OK2.